# How do I add an event listener to a Highcharts object *AFTER* I've created it

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to add an event listener to a highcharts object after it's been created. I can add one during declaration. When I try to use the chrome console to sort out where to attach a listener post declaration I can't.

Comment: Why do you need to add an event listener after the chart has been created?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you want to add an event listener after the chart is already created, the documentation provides some insight regarding [extending highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts):

> Events can be added to the instance through framework event binding. If your framework is *jQuery*, you can for example run `$(chart).bind('load', someFunction);`

There is even some mention in the *"Hooking up to Chart.init"* section (on the same page) as to how you might bind an event after the chart has rendered, but it is a more invasive solution. I've adapted the code sample below with some modifications:

```
// General, global event listener
var globalCallback = function (chart) {

    // Specific event listener
    Highcharts.addEvent(chart.container, 'click', function (e) {
        e = chart.pointer.normalize();
        console.log('Clicked chart at ' + e.chartX + ', ' + e.chartY );
    ​});

    // Specific event listener
    Highcharts.addEvent(chart.xAxis[0], 'afterSetExtremes', function (e) {
        console.log('Set extremes to ' + e.min + ', ' + e.max);
    });
}

// Add `globalCallback` to the list of highcharts callbacks
Highcharts.Chart.prototype.callbacks.push(globalCallback);
```

You can also [take a look at their example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/K7pN9/) for this scenario.

Comment: Thank you! Can someone else please vote up this answer? I asked the question but don't have enough points to do so.

Comment: You can also accept this answer (if it works for you) by clicking the checkmark beside my answer.