# How to listenTo afterSetExtremes event in Highcharts from Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, highcharts

I am trying to use **Highcharts** for plotting charts and also wants them to be zoomable.

Below is chart I am plotting

```
var mychart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            type: 'line',
            zoomType: 'x'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
});
```

I am able to see chart and its zoomable.
but what I want to do is listen for **afterSetExtremes** event from my backbone view.

Below is what I tried to do for listening event.

```
this.listenTo(mychart.chartOptions.xAxis, 'afterSetExtremes', function() {
    console.log("listening to ");
});
```

But I am getting error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Am I missing something or doing it wrong?
How can I listen for **afterSetExtremes** event without mentioning it inside **xAxis.events** option from my backbone view ?

Thanks

Comment: this discussion may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277517/how-do-i-add-an-event-listener-to-a-highcharts-object-after-ive-created-it

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
mychart.chartOptions.xAxis
```

with

```
mychart.chartOptions.xAxis.events
```